# How to log in using webDriver in Chrome

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing an automation test in ebay using Selenium.
I want to log in. I managed to put the email, but I'm having a problem with the password.
the code is :

```
      // put email address and press "continue" bottom          
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#userid")).sendKeys("1234@gmail.com");
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#signin-continue-btn")).click();
      
      // put password and press "sign in" bottom
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pass")).sendKeys("1234");
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sgnBt")).click();
```

Comment: _automation test in ebay using Selenium_: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the password field is taking longer to load than the email field. Try adding a wait before entering the password to ensure that the field is fully loaded. You can use the WebDriverWait class to wait for an element to become visible, clickable, or have a certain attribute value.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement passwordField = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#pass")));
```